# How to call database attributes in models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a project with ruby on rails, i have recipes table in the db recipes table has user_id etc. Also i have a user table and in this table i have an attribute called n_days. I am using sidekiq to do some background processes (for automatically delete in n days) In models(recipe.rb) i need to reach user_id(in recipe table) and n_days(in user table) but i do not know how to access them.

i tried this code but i get NoMethodError

```
scope :recent, -> { where('created_at <= :a', a: Time.now - User.find_by(id: :user_id.to_s.to_i).n_days.days) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simplier to set `deleted_at` datetime field in your sidekiq worker, it will make easier to compare datetimes. However, if you want to use `n_days` integer column, you can write such code:

```rb
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :text, presence: true

  # scope :recent,
  #   -> {
  #     joins(:user)
  #     .where.not(users: { deleted_at: nil })
  #     .where('recipes.created_at <= users.deleted_at')
  #   }

  # For SQLite database
  scope :recent,
    -> {
      joins(:user)
      .where("recipes.created_at <= datetime('now', '-' || ifnull(users.n_days, 0) || ' days')")
    }
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipes, dependent: :destroy

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.integer :n_days
      t.datetime :deleted_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :recipes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :text
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# seeds.rb

User.destroy_all

10.times do |t|
  r = rand(15)
  u = User.create!(
    first_name: SecureRandom.uuid,
    last_name: SecureRandom.uuid,
    n_days: rand(15),
    deleted_at: Time.now - r.days
  )
  5.times do |t|
    u.recipes.create!(
      name: SecureRandom.uuid,
      text: SecureRandom.uuid,
      created_at: 60.days.ago
    )
  end
end

p Recipe.recent.inspect
```